# What is the cost of cross-region reading SQS messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

I have a SQS queue created in TY3 AWS region and I write messages in it from an EC2 box that also lives in TYO3.

I want to read those messages from an EC2 box located in US-EAST-1.

What is the cost of this cross-region reading? Is it specified somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discussed with AWS support and it seems that there are no additional costs for cross-region reads. You will be charged with "Data Transfer Out" prices for the source region (the region where the queue is created): https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/